# [@RNC/AsyncStorage]: NativeModule: AsyncStorage is null

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

Just to be up front, I have reviewed every search and article I can find on this topic. I am working on just the Android app to get some underlying issues updated in Android Studio. This is just a relatively simple flashcard-type app.

I have cleaned, rebuilt, and run through every fix I can find.

I'm getting the error:
`Error: [@RNC/AsyncStorage]: NativeModule: AsyncStorage is null.

```
                                                                                            To fix this issue try these steps:
                                                                                            
                                                                                              • Rebuild and restart the app.
                                                                                            
                                                                                              • Run the packager with `--reset-cache` flag.
                                                                                            
                                                                                              • If you are using CocoaPods on iOS, run `pod install` in the `ios` directory and then rebuild and re-run the app.
                                                                                            
                                                                                              • If this happens while testing with Jest, check out docs how to integrate AsyncStorage with it: https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/advanced/jest
                                                                                            
                                                                                            If none of these fix the issue, please open an issue on the Github repository: https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage/issues`
```

I'll include the relevant files & commands below, but please let me know if you need more information somewhere:

Firstly, I installed the package with NPM:
'npm install @react-native-async-storage/async-storage'

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Scratch",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.18.1",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^4.1.0",
    "native-base": "^2.13.12",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.6.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "29.5.0",
    "jest": "29.5.0",
    "jetifier": "^2.0.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.76.5",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "setupFiles": [
      "./jest/jestSetupFile.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

^ Just one note on the above, I did try upgrading native-base as well.

Deck.js
'''
import React from 'react'
import { Platform, Image, Dimensions, TouchableOpacity, View, Animated, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { Card, CardItem, Icon, Container, Header, Body, Footer, Left, Right, Content, Title, List, ListItem, Text, Button } from 'native-base'
import Swiper from 'react-native-swiper'
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
'''

I can provide more code if needed, but when I comment out the above import, the app functions. If I include the import from Native base, I get the removal notification, and if I simply comment out the AsyncStorage, the app otherwise functions with the AsyncStorage functionality.

I ran two different codes in my jestSetupFile, the suggested one here: https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/advanced/jest and the current one:
'''
jest.mock("@react-native-async-storage/async-storage", () => ({ setItem: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()), getItem: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()), }));
'''

I also went the mocks_ directory route.

Are there any other suggestions?

I followed the error message to the letter. I have deleted and added the app back both on the emulator and a physical device. I also created the .apk and ran it on my phone just to make sure it wasn't a jest issue.